# Python (kivy) - Continuous key press causes a loop?

Tags: python, keyboard, key, kivy, pressed

My code works fine when I press the spacebar once at a time. However, when continuously pressed it creates a loop of some sort and crashes.
What might be the reason and how can I fix this? Thanks!!

```
import kivy
import csv
import time
# import xlsxwriter
import sys

kivy.require('1.0.8')
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window, Keyboard
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from scipy.spatial import distance
from kivy.clock import Clock
import numpy

Window.size = (1280, 1024)
Window.fullscreen = True

a = 78.3
b = 156.6
c = 234.9
q = 30
L = 250
R = 1015
O = 630

stim_list = [1, a, q, c, q, b, q, b, q, c, q, c, q, c, q, a, q, b, q, b, q, c, q, a, q, a, q, b, q, a, q, a, q, b, q, c,

             q, a, q, b, q, a, q, c, q, c, q, a, q, b, q, b, q, c, q, a, q, a, q, b, q, b, q, a, q, c, q, c, q, c, q, b,

             q, b, q, c, q, c, q, a, q, b, q, a, q, b, q, b, q, b, q, a, q, c, q, a, q, c, q, c, q, c, q, b, q, b, q, b,

             q, c, q, b, q, c, q, a, q, a, q, a, q]

side_list = [1, R, O, L, O, L, O, R, O, R, O, R, O, L, O, R, O, L, O, R, O, L, O, R, O, L, O, R, O, R, O, L, O, L, O, R,

             O, R, O, R, O, L, O, L, O, R, O, R, O, R, O, L, O, L, O, L, O, L, O, L, O, R, O, L, O, L, O, L, O, R, O, L,

             O, L, O, R, O, R, O, L, O, L, O, L, O, L, O, R, O, R, O, R, O, L, O, R, O, L, O, R, O, L, O, R, O, R, O, R,

             O, L, O, L, O, R, O, L, O, R, O, R, O]

side_list_b = side_list[::-1]
stim_list_b = stim_list[::-1]
i = 0
stimwidth = 45
initialx = 650

# workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('MT.xlsx')
# worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
# row = 0
# col = 0

class MyKeyboardListener(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(MyKeyboardListener, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_released, self)
        self._keyboard = keyboard
        keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._keyboard_on_key_down)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            # If it exists, this widget is a VKeyboard object which you can use
            # to change the keyboard layout.    
            pass    
        # self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)    
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)    
        self.startTime = time.time()    
        self.endTime = time.time()    
        self.stage = 0    
        self.firstTouch = []    
        self.isPressed = False
        self.stimPresented = time.time()    
        self.fileName = sys.argv[1]    
        f = open(self.fileName, 'w+')    
        f.close()    

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard have been closed!')
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    # def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
    #     print('The key', keycode[0], 'have been pressed')
    #     # print(' - text is %r' % text)
    #     # print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)
    #     if (keycode[0] == 32):
    #         print("sapce is printed")

    def _on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        print('The key', keycode[0], 'have been pressed')
        # print(' - text is %r' % text)
        # print(' - modifiers are %r' % modifiers)
        #space key is up
        if (keycode[0] == 32):
            print("sapce is released")
            self.stage = 1
            self.startTime = time.time()
            self.add_diff_row(self.startTime,self.stimPresented)
            self.isPressed = False

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # if touch.is_double_tap:
        print("touch")
        touch.multitouch_sim = False

        if (self.stage == 2):
            # print(touch.pos)
            # dst = distance.euclidean(self.firstTouch, touch.pos)
            # print(dst)
            a = numpy.array(touch.pos)
            b = numpy.array(self.firstTouch)
            dist = numpy.linalg.norm(a - b)
            print(dist)
            self.add_diff_row(dist*0.02554, 0)
            self.stage = 3

        # screen first press
        if (self.stage == 1):
            self.stage = 2
            self.endTime = time.time()
            self.add_diff_row(self.endTime, self.startTime)
            #print(touch.pos)
            self.firstTouch = touch.pos

    ### Make the keyboard operatble
    def _keyboard_released(self):
        self.focus = False
        ### replace stim with the next one when the keyboard is pressed


    def present_stim(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        self.keycode = 36
        initialy = 400 - (stim_list_b[i] / 2)
        xlab = Label(text='X', pos=(side_list_b[i], 650))
        self.remove_widget(xlab)
        stimPresented = time.time()
        with self.canvas:
            self.canvas.clear()
            self.add_widget(xlab)
            Color(1., 1, 1)
            Rectangle(pos=(initialx, initialy), size=(stimwidth, stim_list_b[i]))

                #see above
            self.add_diff_row(self.endTime,self.startTime)
        ###

    def _keyboard_on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        global i
        if(keycode[0] == 32 and self.isPressed):
            i = i + 1
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.present_stim(keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers), 3)

        # the space key is first down
        if (keycode[0] == 32 and not(self.isPressed)):
            self.isPressed = True
            # add row of time different
            # self.add_diff_row(self.endTime,self.startTime)

    ###


    def add_diff_row(self, value1, value2):
        data = [value1 - value2]
        with open(self.fileName, 'a') as f:
            print (data)
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(data)

    ###Move the stim togetehr with fingers
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        initialy = 400 - (stim_list_b[i] / 2)
        self.canvas.clear()
        self.myWidget = Widget(size=(100, 100))
        self.add_widget(self.myWidget)

        # calculating fingers space only for stage 1.
        # if (self.stage == 2):
        #     #self.add_diff_row(touch.pos[0],0)
        #     print(touch.pos)
        #     self.stage = 3
        #
        # if (self.stage == 3):
        #     print(touch.pos)
        #     self.stage = 4
        #adding differenc in rows.
        #print touch.pos[1]
        if (touch.pos[1] > initialy + stim_list_b[i] + 70) or (touch.pos[1] < initialy - 20):
            with self.myWidget.canvas:
                self.add_widget(Label(text='X', pos=(side_list_b[i], 650)))
                Rectangle(pos=(initialx, initialy), size=(stimwidth, stim_list_b[i]))
        else:
            goodposx = touch.pos[0]
            goodposy = initialy
            with self.myWidget.canvas:
                self.add_widget(Label(text='X', pos=(side_list_b[i], 650)))
                Rectangle(pos=((goodposx - (stimwidth / 2)), initialy), size=(stimwidth, stim_list_b[i]))

                # if 'multitouch_sim' in touch.profile:
                #     print ('multi touch pressed ')
                #     touch.multitouch_sim = False
                #     self.endTime = datetime.datetime.now()
                #     data = [self.startTime,self.endTime]
                #     with open(r'res.csv', 'a') as f:
                #         writer = csv.writer(f)
                #         writer.writerow(data)

# workbook.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(MyKeyboardListener())
```

Comment: You should format your code properly as it is not displaying properly.

Comment: You should also post the error you are getting as it will make helping you a lot easier. It is also a good idea to remove unrelated code (such as all of your commented code) to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Probably error is in function `present_stim`. This line:

```
initialy = 400 - (stim_list_b[i] / 2)
```

Array index `i` is out of range due to long spacebar press.